# Django custom authentication backend - "is_valid" calls authenticate

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am doing my custom auth backend for the first time, and it generally works, but i fail to understand a thing or two and there is some unwanted behaviour in my view.

Basically i just wanted to add an additional mandatory field - domain name which would have to be filled in (or choosen) on login.

So i have my custom DomainUser (AbstractUser) which defines additional "domainname" field

```
class DomainUser(AbstractUser):
    domainname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['domainname', ]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    @property
    def domainusername(self):
        return ''.join([self.domainname, '\\', self.username])
```

then there is the view:

```
def domain_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = DomainLoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            username = login_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            domainname = login_form.cleaned_data.get('domainname')
            raw_password = login_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, domainname=domainname, password=raw_password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:index'))
            else:
                pass # should return invalid logon page
    else:
        login_form = DomainLoginForm()
    
    context = {
        'login_form': login_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'domain_auth/login.html', context)
```

And the auth:

```
class DomainLDAPBackend(BaseBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, domainname=None, password=None):
        #return DomainUser.objects.get(username__iexact=username, domainname__iexact=domainname)
        return DomainUser.objects.get(username__iexact=username)

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return DomainUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except DomainUser.DoesNotExists:
            return None
```

Auth is a complete placeholder for now (it doesn't really authenticates the use with domain, but that's just temporary), it's just for test purpose before i connect here my real auth module.

My loginform has the domainname field as well and it works.

I have two issues:
I fill my login form and the view is being called:

1. It seems that "authenticate" is called 2 times in my "domain_login" view, first time is by "is_valid" method and this first time it passes "domainname" parameter in authenticate as None.
   Why is it called here? Is it a normal behaviour? I couldn't find anything like this in the documentation, but i suppose there is an error in my code.
   Second manual call in my view is correct - all parameters are passed as forseen, login works as well.
2. What's the purpose of get_user method? It's called only after logging on (and while using admin, especially browsing user model), but not while authenticating.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Authentication backend**

```
# Override ModelBackend instead of BaseBackend, so you get various methods out of the box
class DomainLDAPBackend(ModelBackend):
    # Don' t set default values for username, domainname and password (so they are manadatory)
    def authenticate(self, request, username, domainname, password):
        try:
            # iexact is used by default
            user = DomainUser.objects.get(username=username, domainname=domainname)
            # Checks the password
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return
```

If you want that users can choose the domainname at login change `authenticate` (I suggest you to request domainname at sign up):

```
def authenticate(self, request, username, domainname, password):
    try:
        user = DomainUser.objects.get(username=username)
        if user.check_password(password):
            if user.domainname is None:
                user.domainname = domainname
                user.save()
                return user
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return
```

**Views**

```
def domain_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = DomainLoginForm(data=request.POST)
        # There is not need to call login_form.is_valid: access POST data directly, the validation is performed by DomainLDAPBackend
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        domainname = request.POST.get('domainname')
        raw_password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, domainname=domainname, password=raw_password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:index'))
        else:
            pass # Should return invalid login page
    else:
        login_form = DomainLoginForm()
    
    return render(request, 'domain_auth/login.html', {'login_form': login_form})
```

Note that there is not need to override `ModelBackend.get_user` that does not conflict with your custom user model. That method is used internally by Django to retrieve info about the logged user. Remember to set `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` and `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.

**Edit**

I have analyzed the code of `AuthenticationForm` on [GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/forms.py), I have found that it is already authenticating the user in `validate` (that is the reason why your original code was calling `authenticate` two times). First you need to override `validate` that by default don' t use your custom backend method:

```
class DomainLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        domainname = self.cleaned_data.get('domainname')

        if username is not None and password is not None and domainname is not None:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, domainname=domainname, password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
            else:
                self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache) # Raises an exception if the user is not active, you can override this method

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Then in your views you can simply write:

```
def domain_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = DomainLoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            # If the form is valid, DomainLoginForm.get_user() never returns None
            user = login_form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:index'))
    else:
        login_form = DomainLoginForm()
    
    return render(request, 'domain_auth/login.html', {'login_form': login_form})
```

Comment: What's `DomainLoginForm`?

Comment: DomainLoginForm is the custom login form derived from AuthentifcationForm - there is just one field added - domainname. It seemed to work (Field and requested data), so i didn't put the code there.